# How to press button from keyboard instead of using mouse in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and I'm trying to create a calculator similar to windows calculator for practicing. I have created a calculator UI using tkinter.

If I press any key from keyboard, the button should be pressed in the calculator window similar to windows calculator. I have given justify as left for l1. But it is aligned in center only. I don't know where I'm wrong. Also I need to know how to create a sliding menu in tkinter.

Any ideas will be really helpful.

Below is the code of my calculator UI.

```
#Importing required libraries
from tkinter import *
import math
import fractions
import tkinter.font as font
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

#Creating instance for window
win = Tk()

#Function for reset
def reset(dummy=None):
    e1.delete(0, 'end')
    e2.delete(0, 'end')

#Function for backspace
def backspace():
    x = str(e2.get())
    e2.delete(0, END)
    e2.insert(0, x[:-1])

#Function for button click
def click(number):
    x = e2.get()
    e2.delete(0, END)
    e2.insert(0, str(x) + str(number))

#Giving title to window
win.title('Calculator')
#Customizing main=window
win.geometry('330x443')
win.configure(bg='#e8e8e8')
win.resizable(0,0)

#Defining Font style
l1_font = font.Font(family='Georgia', size=15)
e1_font = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=15)
e2_font = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=35)
b_font = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=15)

#Binding enter and escape to window

win.bind('<Return>')
win.bind('<Escape>', reset)

#Frame1
f1 = Frame(win, bg='#e6e6e6')
f1.pack()

#Frame1 - Label1
l1 = Label(f1, text='Calculator', justify='left', anchor='w', justify='left', bg='#e6e6e6', pady=20)
l1['font'] = l1_font
l1.pack()

#Frame2
f2 = Frame(win, bg='#e6e6e6')
f2.pack()

#Frame2 - Entry1
e1 = Entry(f2, width = 65, justify = 'right', bg='#e6e6e6', validate="key", relief=FLAT)
#e1['validatecommand'] = (e1.register(entry_validation),'%P','%d')
e1['font'] = e1_font
e1.pack()

#Frame2 - Entry2
e2 = Entry(f2, width = 65, justify = 'right', bg='#e6e6e6', validate="key", relief=FLAT)
#e2['validatecommand'] = (e2.register(entry_validation),'%P','%d')
e2['font'] = e2_font
e2.pack()

#Frame3
f3 = Frame(win, bg='#e6e6e6')
f3.pack()

#Frame3 - Buttons
button1 = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='white', command=lambda: click(1))
button2 = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='white', command=lambda: click(2))
button3 = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='white', command=lambda: click(3))
button4 = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='white', command=lambda: click(4))
button5 = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='white', command=lambda: click(5))
button6 = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='white', command=lambda: click(6))
button7 = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='white', command=lambda: click(7))
button8 = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='white', command=lambda: click(8))
button9 = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='white', command=lambda: click(9))
button0 = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='white', command=lambda: click(0))

button_add = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='#f7f7f7', command=lambda: click('+'))
button_sub = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='#f7f7f7', command=lambda: click('-'))
button_mult = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='#f7f7f7', command=lambda: click('*'))
button_div = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='#f7f7f7', command=lambda: click('/'))

button_dot = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='white', command=lambda: click('.'))
button_enter = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='#9aafed')
button_clear = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='#f7f7f7', command=reset)
button_bs = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='#f7f7f7', command=backspace)

button_space = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='#f7f7f7', command=lambda: click(' '))
button_na2 = Button(f3, height =3, width =10, relief=FLAT, bg='white', command=reset)

#Shoving buttons into window

#Frame3 - Buttons - Row 1
button_clear.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)
button_div.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)
button_mult.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)
button_bs.grid(row = 0, column = 3, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)

#Frame3 - Buttons - Row 2
button7.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)
button8.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)
button9.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)
button_sub.grid(row = 1, column = 3, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)

#Frame3 - Buttons - Row 3
button4.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)
button5.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)
button6.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)
button_add.grid(row = 2, column = 3, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)

#Frame3 - Buttons - Row 4
button1.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)
button2.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)
button3.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)
button_space.grid(row = 3, column = 3, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)

#Frame3 - Buttons - Row 5
button_na2.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)
button0.grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)
button_dot.grid(row = 4, column = 2, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)
button_enter.grid(row = 4, column = 3, padx=0.75, pady=0.75)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

For capturing keyboard events try code below. Example taken from [effbot.org](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

```
def key(event):
print("pressed", repr(event.char))

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Key>", key)
frame.focus_set()
frame.pack()
```

You used justify twice. Maybe this is the problem.

```
l1 = Label(f1, text='Calculator', justify='left', anchor='w', justify='left', bg='#e6e6e6', pady=20)
```

To create sliding menu you can try using scale widget. More info again on [effbot.org](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scale.htm)

[Scrollbar example effbot.org](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm)

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

left_frame = Frame(root, height=200, width=200, background='green')
left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
right_frame = Frame(root, height=200, width=200)
right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(right_frame)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
listbox = Listbox(right_frame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
for i in range(1000):
    listbox.insert(END, str(i))
listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```

Comment: I have tried removing second justify but still it is not left aligning. Regarding sliding menu, I'm asking for menu similar to windows calculator sliding menu. You have given answer for sliding bar.

Comment: @AravindSelvan I edited my answer and added scrollbar example. If you are looking for different widgets just check effbot.org or youtube tutorials. I'm not quite sure what you mean by calculator menu.